# How to create a dynamic column in a SQL Server database and report VB.NET?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I have problem to design a form with dynamic DataGridView which contains dynamic columns.

The idea was make DataGridView columns and rows show all the departments of the company at the same order of row and column to show the numbers of messages they sent to each other (from D1 row to D2  column), that's was easy if I made database table columns fixed.

But the problem is how can I do this idea with dynamic database table columns and repot page columns, if the company add new department?

In that case I need to add a new column in databse table and report page

[image image of tables i made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzPpH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are different ways you can store data but only the difference is how you present it.

In your case you want to present the data in row wise column which you can design in code side also.

Main point is how you store the data.

For that you can store data in normalized form by making different tables for department and its related messages as "Department" and "DepartmentMessageDetails".

Or you can also store it in denormalized form in a single table.

While making report. You can create a stored procedure and design your table there by using dynamic SQL script.

Sample:

```
DECLARE @Department TABLE
(
    DNAM NVARCHAR(100),
    DNO INT
)
INSERT INTO @Department
        ( DNAM, DNO )
VALUES  ( N'D1', 1),
        ( N'D2', 2),
        ( N'D3', 3)

DECLARE @Message TABLE
(
    DNO INT,
    [D1] NVARCHAR(100),
    [D2] NVARCHAR(100),
    [D3] NVARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO @Message
        ( DNO, D1, D2, D3 )
VALUES  ( 1, N'T1_D1', N'T1_D2', N'T1_D3')--, ( 1, N'Test3 D2')
        ,( 1, N'', N'Test1 D1', N'')
        ,( 1, N'T1_D1', N'', N'')
        ,( 1, N'', N'T1_D2', N'')
        ,( 1, N'', N'', N'T1_D3')
        ,( 1, N'', N'', N'T1_D3')

        ,( 2, N'T2_D1', N'T2_D2', N'T2_D3')--, ( 2, N'Test3 D2')
        ,( 2, N'T2_D1', N'', N'')
        ,( 2, N'', N'T2_D2', N'')
        ,( 2, N'', N'', N'T2_D3')
        ,( 2, N'', N'', N'T2_D3')
        ,( 2, N'', N'', N'T2_D3')

        ,( 3, N'T3_D1', N'T3_D2', N'T3_D3')--, ( 3, N'Test3 D3')
        ,( 3, N'T3_D1', N'', N'')
        ,( 3, N'', N'T3_D2', N'')
        ,( 3, N'', N'', N'T3_D3')

SELECT * FROM @Department
SELECT * FROM @Message

;WITH T AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        (CASE WHEN DNO = 1 THEN 'D1'
            WHEN DNO = 2 THEN 'D2'
            WHEN DNO = 3 THEN 'D3'
        END) AS Names
        , DNO
    FROM 
        @Message    
)
SELECT 
    T1.Names ,
    (CASE 
        WHEN T1.Names = 'D1' THEN -1 
        WHEN T1.Names = 'D2' THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Message M WHERE (M.DNO = 1) AND (ISNULL(M.D2, '') <> ''))
        ELSE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Message M WHERE (M.DNO = 1) AND (ISNULL(M.D3, '') <> '')) 
    END) AS D1 ,
    (CASE WHEN T1.Names = 'D2' THEN -1  
        WHEN T1.Names = 'D1' THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Message M WHERE (M.DNO = 2) AND (ISNULL(M.D1, '') <> ''))
        ELSE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Message M WHERE (M.DNO = 2) AND (ISNULL(M.D3, '') <> ''))
    END) AS D2 ,
    (CASE WHEN T1.Names = 'D3' THEN -1  
        WHEN T1.Names = 'D2' THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Message M WHERE (M.DNO = 3) AND (ISNULL(M.D2, '') <> ''))
        ELSE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Message M WHERE (M.DNO = 3) AND (ISNULL(M.D1, '') <> ''))
    END) AS D3
FROM T T1
```

In this sample I have used hard coded column names but this also can be handled if we write dynamic query, which I have skipped for later.

Comment: thanx for your help but do you can explain mor about sql script

Comment: Actually, I have updated my answer and added a sample for you with respect to your described conditions. For reporting SQL scripts are better options. I have produced similar report without using Dynamic SQL, just by using simple SQL Script. Hope this will help you.